# date_default reverts to server time not local time

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have set the default date and timezone to Brisvegas Australia using

`date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane')`

on other pages/scripts I can call `echo date('m-d-Y')` and it returns the correct date.  So far so good. However...and this is probably a very newb problem, when I try and pass the `date()` to variable to use in and insertion or query, the `date()` is the timezone of my server (LA). `$today = date('d-m-Y')` Not helpful.

So why does echo `date(d-m-Y)` print my real date but passing it to a variable doesn't?

Comment: edit your post and add the code you've mentioned where you're passing a variable

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane') is in my header script.  $today = date('d-m-Y') is at the top of another script page.  If I go echo $today it returns the date in LA but at the bottom of the same page I have echo date('d-m-Y')    and it prints my local date.